# Divide df.loc by df.loc with NaN values; error 'str' / 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, nan, divide, pandas-loc

I am working with a large csv file (1.8 GB) and am trying to divide two variables (rows) by each other to create a new variable. It works for some variables; however, not for all. The code is as described below:

```
#get the variables out
    df1 = DF_GLOBAL.loc[DF_GLOBAL['VARIABLE'] == var_1]
    df2 = DF_GLOBAL.loc[DF_GLOBAL['VARIABLE'] == var_2]
#stack them to easier divide them
#I also do that to avoid dividing explainatory varaiables by each other, such as unit of the values

    df1 = df1.set_index(['STACK_VAR_1', 'STACK_VAR_2','STACK_VAR_3'])
    df2 = df2.set_index(['STACK_VAR_1', 'STACK_VAR_2','STACK_VAR_3'])
    
        

    df3 = df2.loc[:,first_year:] / df1.loc[:,first_year:]
#df3 is the desired outcome of the division, which is later attached to the DF_GLOBAL again.
```

The error message I get is:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Indicating, that some of the values are strings that are divide. Therefore, I am wondering how I would be able to skip strings (probably 'NaN'). It is not possible for me to loop through the dataframe, as it is too large for it to be efficient.

Comment: The easiest way would be to delete null values (NaN) before dividing, using e.g. DataFrame.dropna(). Have you considered this?

Comment: Yes, but it is not really feasible for me here, as I do not want to drop rows completely. Some rows have values from 1990 (year) onwards, other from 2000 or 2010 etc. And if I start in 1990, I would still like to have the rows with the data from e.g. 2000 to be divide from 2000 onwards. - But thank you already for the possible solution :)